# Is this code creating a getter? I am trying to translate this to C#

Tags: c#, vb6, vb6-migration

```
Private Samples As Collection
Public Function Count() As Integer

    Count = Samples.Count

End Function
```

I am trying to translate this code into C#. I am also trying to understand this code's logic. I currently have this code,

```
Public int Count {get; set;}
```

This is written in c#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, if it says `Function`, it means function. Conversely, if it said `Property` it would be a property and *could* then (optionally) only contain a getter.

The precise equivalent is:

```
public int Count() {
  return Samples.Count;
}
```

Where you may have been tripped up is looking at the calling code - in VB, the parentheses are optional when calling a parameterless function, so you may see code that invokes the above function just saying `Count` rather than `Count()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
private Collection<object> Samples { get; set; }
public int Count() {
  return  Samples.Count;
}
```

Comment: the other answer is the optimized.. this one is how it looks like

Answer (score 1):

This is the equivalent implemented as a Property (Like you tried to do):

```
public int Count
{
    get
    {
        return Samples.Count;
    }
}
```

The exact equivalent : As a normal method you would do this:

```
public int Count()
{
    return Samples.Count;
}
```

However, the below code creates a default setter and getter. You don't need a setter in your case, and the getter doesn't return the value of _count hidden field. But it returns the count of the list.

```
Public int Count {get; set;}
```

Those are auto-implemented properties which are equivalent to:

```
private int _count;
public int get_Count()
{
   return _count();
}

public void set_Count(int value)
{
   _count = value;
}
```